# get the selected item from list in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me

i am working with j2me List.It contain many elements.I want when i select the any of them 
i can use it value in my required function.e.g in my code i select a number when i select it
i press a command chat a text area is shown when i write some text there this i can get easily
but how the selected element from list how i can get it .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Object Of List>.getSelectedIndex();
```

You can maintain a Vector which have the same data as filled in List Component.
Now you can get getSelectedIndex and can retrieve object from Vector from the position to get the selected Data.